# Are weights 1-D or 2-D in softmax Regression?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, softmax

I've learned ML and have been learning DL from Andrew N.G's coursera courses, and every time he talks about a linear classifier, the weights are just a 1-D vector. 
Even during the assignments, when we roll an image into a 1-D vector(pixels * 3), the weights would still be a 1-D vector.

I now have started O'Reilly's "Learning TensorFlow" book, and came across the first example. The weights initialization in tensorflow was a bit different.

The book says the following(Page 14):

"Since we are not going to use the spatial information at this point, we will unroll our image pixels as a single long vector denoted x (Figure 2-2). Then
$xw^0 = ∑x_i w^0_i$
will be the evidence for the image containing the digit 0 (and in the same way we will have $w^d$ weight vectors for each one of the other digits, d = 1, . . . , 9)."

and the corresponding TensorFlow code:

```
data = input_data.read_data_sets(DATA_DIR, one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))

y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
y_pred = tf.matmul(x, W)
```

Why are the weights 2-D here. Are weights 2-D in softmax Linear Classifier?
In the coursera course, when he taught Softmax Linear Classifier, he still says the weights are 1-D. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You are right that weights are 1-D, but that is just for 1 neuron.
If you consider a straightforward layered neural network, it will have some number of layers(Just 1 layer with 10 neurons in your code). So, in tensorflow, the weights variable contains weights for entire layer and not a single neuron, which makes it a 2-D array.

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
```

This line means that there are 10 neurons, each with a weight array of length 784.
One rule of thumb to understand this in tensorflow is that weight dimentions are written as..

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_of_previous_layer, output_of_current_layer]))
```

or

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([input_of_current_layer, input_of_next_layer]))
```

You can read more about this at [Intro to Neural Networks](https://medium.com/preeminence/neural-networks-part-1-af2444ea4dc0)